# MYSQL join on subquery optimization

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, subquery

This is a distilled version of the query that I am trying to run:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE foo = 'bar') t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

The above query is incredibly slow because MYSQL fails to notice that the subquery in the join i.e. `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE foo = 'bar'` has `id` as a primary key which it can use in the join clause.

Ofcourse, I should have written this query as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.foo = 'bar';
```

But, the problem is that the subquery(`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE foo = 'bar'`) is generated by a library that I do not control. What is the best way for me to optimize this given that I cannot do much about the subquery since I programmatically get it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What's the MySQL version?

MariaDB 10 can do the "merge" - automatically transforming the first query to the second one internally.

MySQL 5.6 cannot do that afaik, but it can materialize the derived table into a temporary one and add automatic indexes - [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html).

And you could emulate that even in older versions. If you always get some code for a  then you can do

```
create temporary table t_indexed as <subquery>;
alter tably t_indexed add key(id);

SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN t_indexed t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

If you always know the structure of the  results, you can create the temp table with this structure and proper indexes in place and use `insert ... select` instead.

Comment: I am on MYSQL 5.6. And, no, its not always the same code I get - the subquery is generated based on user input which I pass into the library I don't control.

Comment: Then check the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) for your query (or both of them) to see how it is executed.

Comment: I understand the code is not the same, but does it always select from the same table or does it add some joins sometimes etc? If the library gives you the subquery as text, you can use that in many statements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the subquery can have other joins and filters insider. I will give Maria a try.

Comment: You can always to the `create temporary table t_indexed as <subquery>`, that will create the right structure dynamically for you. Then just add the right index for that - but afaik 5.6 should be already doing it, did you check the EXPLAIN? (seeing the plan is very important for any query optimization)

Comment: 5.6 is not doing that. The EXPLAIN says it is selecting all rows from the inner query. I verified on Maria using same dataset - On Maria, this query takes about ~10ms, on MYSQL it takes ~10s.

Comment: What specific version if 5.6 it is? Is it some after GA? (I mostly use MariaDB so do not know the specific details.. but from the manual it seemed like it should be able to do the same :( )

Comment: I am on RDS MYSQL - 5.16.19B

Comment: try running `SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G` to see the [configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/switchable-optimizations.html) of the optimizer to see if materialization is allowed etc.

Comment: Yes it is: `index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on`

Comment: "based on user input" = "asking for trouble"